# Unexpected token { while compiling EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

Here is the code... I am trying to only display items with a certain class on the dashboard:

```
<% newListItems.forEach(function(item){ %>
    <% if (currentClasses.includes(item.class) { %>
    <div class="item">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <p class="ptag"><%= item.name %></p>

    </div>
    <% }) %>
    <% }) %>
```

Here is the app.js code for some reference

```
app.get("/todolist", function (req, res) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        const currentClasses = req.user.classes
        Item.find({}, function (err, foundItems) {
            if (foundItems.length === 0) {
                Item.insertMany(defaultItems, function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err)
                    } else {
                        console.log("Success!")
                    }
                })
                res.redirect("/todolist")
            } else {
                console.log(currentClasses)
                res.render("todolist", { newListItems: foundItems })
            }

        })
    } else {
        res.redirect("/login")
    }
});
```

I don't know why the EJS code is giving an unexpected token { error because the brackets and parenthesis seem to add up

Answer (score 2):

```
<% newListItems.forEach(function(item){ %>
    <% if (currentClasses.includes(item.class)) { %>
    <div class="item">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <p class="ptag"><%= item.name %></p>

    </div>
    <% } %>
    <% }) %>
```

You were closing the parenthesis for the `if` statement in the penultimate line